# Dot diagram (aka Young diagram) method for finding a rational cannonical basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to use the method described in Friedberg, Insel and Spence's
Linear Algebra textbook to solve the following problem (cf. Freidberg,Insel
and Spence pp 534-545 4th ed.). The Authors call this the Dot diagram method. Some authors call his the Young Diagram method.

Here is the problem.

Let $$A= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}5 & -6 & -6 \\-1 & 4 & 2 \\3 & -6 & -4\end{array}\right) $$
Let $C$ be the rational canonical form of this matrix. Find a matrix $P$ such 
that $C=P^{-1}AP$.

My thoughts: I know how to find the RCF (using the invariant factor method for a 3 by 3 matrix). Instead I tried to follow the examples
given on this textbook and use the 'dot diagram' method to find the RCF and this matrix $P$.

Here is what I did: The monic irreducible divisors of the characteristic polynomial $f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)$ of $A$ are $p_1(x)=(x-2)$ and $p_2(x)=(x-1)$. So there will be two sets of dot diagrams, one for $p_1$ and another for $p_2$.

1) Dot diagram for $p_1$.
We have $\dim (\ker(p_1(A))=2$. So the total number of dots
in the dot diagram for $p_1$ is 2. Let $r_i$ denote the number of dots in the $i$th row of the dot diagram. Then $r_1=\frac{1}{1} \left(3-rank(A-2I) \right)=2$.
And so the dot diagram for $p_1$ is two dots in the first row and only that. This means that the dot diagram corresponding to $p_2$ has two columns (And this contributes two companion matrices) $C_1=(2)$ and $C_2=(2)$. But unfortunately, that's not how the actual RCF of $A$ going to look like.

My question is what am I doing wrong with regards to 'dot diagram' method?.
I tried to find more examples of this 'dot diagram' method on the web but to no avail. So if somebody knows where I can find more examples of 'dot diagram' method,that would help me a great deal.

Can anybody kindly help me on this.

Your comments and answers are always greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this can be used to find Jordan form as well. But I am looking specifically for the Rational canonical form. Not Jordan form.

Comment: More precisely not only does this give you the canonical form but it also gives you a way to figure out the basis that does the job as well.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.numbertheory.org/pdfs/canonical.pdf